# set files path in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

im updating a project , the problem is that all images src and header links and etc have path like this:

```
src="/media/js/hoverIntent.js"
```

and i cant see every thing ok on localhost

when i delete the first '/' in src every thing is ok. but the project is very big and i cant delete one by one , 
how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` to point the failing URLs to the correct ones.

As example: your application uses URLs like `/media/js/hoverIntent.js` but everytime the URL begins with `/media` and you have the data stored on your dev server in `/myapp/media/...`. In this case you can solve it by placing following `.htaccess` in your root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /myapp/media/$1
```

Sure, you need to adjust the target URL of your files on localhost